# Get control properties inside control component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I created a custom input component but I want to work with errors inside the component. So to make validation work I need to get errors from control object. Is it possible?

I did my component exactly like [here](http://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel).

Top part of the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sc-input',
  styles,
  template: `
    <label class="label">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <input class="input" [(ngModel)]='value' [attr.name]='name' [attr.type]='type'
             (blur)='onBlur($event)' (focus)='onFocus($event)'>
      <div class="errors">
        <div class="errors__messages"><ng-content select="sc-error-messages"></ng-content></div>
        <div class="errors__indicator"></div>
      </div>
    </label>
  `,
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  ...
}
```

Solved problem by :host classes, but still want to know if there is a way to get control inside its component..

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you created.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Added the code. I can't figure out how to get errors object. `this` doesn't contain it I guess I need an injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should still work in the new forms module:

```
export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  constructor(private control:NgControl, private ngModel:NgModel) {}
}
```

**Update**

Just found https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7391#issuecomment-246120184

It suggests

```
constructor(private _injector:Injector) {
   this.control = this._injector.get(NgControl).control;
}
```

Comment: Accessing the control in the constructor like this didn't work for me, since it was always null. Getting the `NgControl` in `writeValue` (as the github issue suggests) or in `ngAfterViewInit()` did work however.

Comment: Interesting, but IMHO weird.

Comment: I was using it with dart though, not typescript, so maybe there are differences in that regard.

Comment: Probably not. In the end the TS code from the Plunker worked for you in Dart as well.