# How to access NgFormControl in custom Ng2 form element

Tags: angular, dart, angular2-forms, angular-dart

I wrote my own custom form element `DateInputComponent` by implementing `ControlValueAccessor` and use it like this:

```
<my-date-input ngControl="date"></my-date-input>
```

From what I understand, `ngControl` is syntactic sugar for `[ngFormControl]="myControlGroup.controls['date']"`.

Now, inside my `DateInputComponent` I would like to access the `NgFormControl`.

I tried to bind it with `@Input NgFormControl ngFormControl;` but it never gets set, and I tried injecting it with `DateInputComponent(NgFormControl ngFormControl)` but that fails because there is no provider.

What is the correct approach to get it?

(Maybe I'm also approaching it the wrong way... I'd like for this `DateInputComponent` to be able to display all validation errors by itself that might occur.)

Comment: Where does `ngFormControl` come from?

Comment: As I said, from what I understood, `ngControl="date"` is syntactic sugar for assigning this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with the solution [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39429214/170851) suggest: by injecting the `Injector` and reading the `NgControl` out of it:

```dart
class DateInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit {
  Injector _injector;
  DateInputComponent(this._injector);

  NgControl control;

  @override
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    control = _injector.get(NgControl).control;
  }
}
```

Directly injecting the `NgControl`, as Ted suggested, doesn't work, because it causes a cyclic dependency.

Trying to access the `NgControl` in the constructor won't work, because it's not available yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right approach with injecting the directive, but the problem is while `ngControl` could be considered syntactic sugar for NgFormControl it isn't the same class.

All of the form controls extend from NgControl and this is what you should be injecting into your component. `DateInputComponent(NgControl ngControl)`

All the form directives are meant to work interchangeably so they all provide NgControl as the interface they are exposing. This allows the user of your date component to use whatever directive works for their use case:

- `NgModel`: if they just want provide or listen to the value
- `NgFormControl`: if they want to provide the control
- `NgControlName`: if they want to use the string identifier into the ControlMap (This is the one you are using above)

Comment: Thanks. But when I try to add `DateInputComponent(NgControl ngControl)` my app doesn't compile anymore, saying: `Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! NgControlName
<my-date-input ngControl="startDate">`

Comment: It is a common pattern that we use so it should be possible. You can see an example here: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/lib/src/components/material_radio/material_radio.dart#L65

You definitely shouldn't need to use an Injector. It is a code smell if I see that in code.